# Getting click of li created in a ColdFusion file

Tags: jquery, html, listview, coldfusion

I have a list of license plate numbers from my school's database that I have put into a list with coldfusion and displayed in html. Looks like this... [image: pretty, no?]

Before I was importing the data to the list through coldfusion, I was hardcoding in data from the database and getting results. However, it's a fairly long list, so hardcoding all the values in wasn't a good option, especially if this list is going to be expanded in the future. So, I just made another CF file to handle throwing them all in the list. That file looks like this:

setPlates.cfm

```
<cfquery name="q_sample" datasource="cars_live">
  SELECT LICENSE FROM veh_rec 
</cfquery>

<cfloop query="q_sample" >
        <li><a href='#Student'><cfoutput>#q_sample.license#</cfoutput></a></li>
</cfloop>
```

and here is how i put them in the list:

```
<div class="ui-grid-solo">
            <div class="ui-block-a"><br></div>
            <div class="ui-block-a"><ul id="plates" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true" data-filter-reveal="true" data-filter-placeholder="Filter Students">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $.get("setPlates.cfm")
        .done(function(data) {
          $("#plates").html(data);
        });
        </script>
        <div id="plates"></div>
    </ul></div>
</div><!-- /grid solo -->
```

However, now my algorithm I had for outputting all the student data doesn't work anymore. My only guess is that creating the li elements in another file doesn't list them the same way as it did when I created them in the same file. Is there a way to get the text of the li clicked even when they're not created in the same file? Below is my click algorithm and CF file that I had working with hardcoded values.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#plates li").click(function() {
        alert("hi");
        var strLicense=$(this).text();
        strLicense=$.trim(strLicense);

        $.get("joey.cfm", { license: strLicense})
        .done(function(data) {
          $("#myResults").html(data);
        });
    });
```

and joey.cfm:

```
<cfparam name="License" default="">

<cfquery name="q_sample" datasource="cars_live">
  SELECT * FROM veh_rec WHERE LICENSE=<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#trim(urldecode(License))#">
</cfquery>

<cfif q_sample.recordcount eq 0> 
No Results found for <cfoutput>"#License#"</cfoutput> 
</cfif>

<cfoutput query="q_sample" >
  <p>License Plate Number: #license# <br><br> Permit ID Number: #decal#<br><br> Student ID Number: #ID#</p>
</cfoutput>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: *"algorithm I had for outputting all the student data doesn't work anymore"* - in what way? I am guessing it is because the list elements aren't originally part of the dom and you're not accounting for it. Probably need something more like `$("#plates").on("click","li",function(){});` instead of `$(#plates li").click()`

Comment: You also have to elements with the ID of "plates" which isn't helping you out any.

Comment: doesnt work as in nothing will print out. no errors, no nothing. It just wont read the click, hence the alert in there. but that snippet of code there might help

as for the two variables with "plates", I realized that soon after posting, thanks for the heads up though.

That code suggestion worked! if you put it in an answer I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to ask a similar question a while ago.  The problem you're facing is that you're trying to interact with objects that don't exist in the DOM when you created the function.  You want to use the jQuery's [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to attach an event to newly created objects. *Bonus tip, `.on()` replaced [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) in jQuery 1.7. so if you've picked up any free code using `live()` or anyone tells you to use `live()` use `on()` instead*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#plates").on("click","li",function() {
        var strLicense=$(this).text();
        strLicense=$.trim(strLicense);
     });
</script>
```

Comment: Great answer! Got me what I needed, thank you :) Especially for the tip about live!